# Не находит i18n en.json | Angular

Tags: angular, frontend, i18n, локализация

Использую мультиязычность либой ngx-translate. В дебаге локально работает хорошо. Диплою приложение на тестовый AppServer а Azure и получаю ошибку в netwokr

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Локально все ок

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашел на просторах интернета, что проблема решается изменением метода `TranslateHttpLoader` на следующий вид.

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient): TranslateHttpLoader {
return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "assets/i18n/", ".json");
}
```

Но безуспешно. В чем проблема?